# Null point object reference in retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

im trying to get data using Retrofit2 to call API. when i open my app it crash immediately. i tried a lot of solutions. i use postman and still see all the data is in json format. can anyone help me? thank you so much

here is my log

```
Process: tdtu.phongtrosinhvien, PID: 4992
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'retrofit2.Call tdtu.phongtrosinhvien.Mode.API.TimTroApi.getdatanewPost()' on a null object reference
```

ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static Retrofit getClient(String url) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .create();
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

aip calling interface

```
@POST("getDataNewlyPostedRoom.php")
Call<List<Post>> getdatanewPost() ;
```

and here in my Home Fragment.

```
private void loadDataNewPost() {
    TimTroApi.getdatanewPost().enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                postArrayList = (ArrayList<Post>) response.body();
                getDataNewPost(postArrayList);
                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("aaa",t.getMessage());
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code/error messages. Add them as text to your question body.

Comment: sorry, my first question and I edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are trying to call a method in object not initialized, you should read the retrofit doc

First create a Service, to call your request, here is the sample from Retrofit doc.

```
GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

[Retrofit Doc](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: i don't think so becase before that i have inserted successfully my data to mysql and now im trying to get data from mysql

Comment: public class ApiUtils {
    public static String TIMTRO_API_URL = "http://192.168.1.4/timtrosinhvien/";

    public static TimTroApi getTimTroSAPI() {
        return ApiClient.getClient(TIMTRO_API_URL).create(TimTroApi.class);
    }
}